# disabling ssh password authentication

Tags: ssh, centos, cpanel, whm

I need some help with configuration on my server. I ran a test for the firewall security and I have a red warning on my CSF firewall security.

Here is what it said:

SSH/Telnet Check

Check SSH PasswordAuthentication    For ultimate SSH security, you should consider disabling PasswordAuthentication and only allow access using PubkeyAuthentication

Can you please advise me with what change I would need to make on the server to get rid of the warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On WHM --> Security Center 
Also search SSH on WHM search box.

This write for you on `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` `PasswordAuthentication no` and restart SSH service.